# Why does JNI's `FindClass` method have weird side effects?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I have encountered a very strange issue with JNI. Can anybody please help me understand what is wrong here?

If I run the code below as-is, I see:

```
(a) 7fb6f022faf0 7fb6f022fb00 0
(b) 7fb6f022faf8 7fb6f022fb00 1
```

If I uncomment the line marked `// (*)`, then I get:

```
(a) 7f6ce822faf0 7f6ce822fb08 1
(b) 7f6ce822fb00 7f6ce822fb08 1
```

With the `(*)` line commented out (*which should be a no-op!*), one instance of `Integer.class` is found to be unequal to another instance of `Integer.class`, using the `Class.equals` method. With the line uncommented, `java.lang.Integer` is looked up twice rather than once in the `test1` method, and for some reason now the two instances of `Integer.class` are found to be equal! (This is on JDK 16.)

What the heck? I don't understand this at all...

`pkg/Test.java`:

```
package pkg;
public class Test {
    public static native void test0();
    public static native void test1(Object... args);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test0();
        test1(7);
    }
}
```

`test.c`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jclass Integer_class_0;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pkg_Test_test0(JNIEnv *env, jclass ignored) {
    Integer_class_0 = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pkg_Test_test1(JNIEnv *env, jclass ignored, 
            jobjectArray args) {
    //(*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");    // (*)
    jobject arg = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, args, 0);
    jclass arg_type = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, arg);
    jclass Integer_class_1 = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");

    jclass cls_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Class");
    jmethodID cls_equals_methodID =
            (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_class, "equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");

    printf("(a) %lx %lx %d\n", Integer_class_0, Integer_class_1,
            (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env,
                    Integer_class_0, cls_equals_methodID, Integer_class_1));
    printf("(b) %lx %lx %d\n", arg_type, Integer_class_1,
            (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env,
                    arg_type, cls_equals_methodID, Integer_class_1));
}
```

Comment: I added the `jvm` tag because there are at least two users that I know track it, and might be able to help you more. This is rather weird, indeed.

Comment: It seems like you're somehow confusing the object "pinning" mechanism. There's no reason that the raw jclass values need to be the same, and you see that they're different. Pinning probably has some "method level" scoping involved, but I'm just guessing. I suspect this should be reported as a bug, but I doubt it would get fixed. There's a bunch of undefined JNI stuff, and the Java Panama project aims to make it obsolete.

Comment: @boneill Yes, I found out the hard way that comparing `jclass` values directly simply does not work. However, that's why I included the call to `Class.equals`. Even that does not work here in one of the two cases! That has to simply be wrong, since `jclass` references can only refer to `Class<?>` objects.

Comment: @Eugene It truly is weird, and I detected several other instances of flakiness of similar form, where depending on the order in which I call JNI methods, I get different behavior. This code example is so simple though that I can't even see how things could possibly go wrong. I agree that if this is a bug it probably wouldn't ever be fixed -- I have tried to report half a dozen bugs to the JDK team before, and none of them seemed to care.

Comment: You can not assume a local reference to stay valid between two different native method invocations. When you use an invalid reference, arbitrary “strange things” can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This entire experiment is built on shaky foundations:

1. `Integer_class_0` is a local reference, which is made invalid when `Java_pkg_Test_test0` returns. Attempting to use it in `Java_pkg_Test_test1` makes no sense. Unless you make it a global reference first with `NewGlobalRef`!
2. The JNI returns *handles* to object references, so it makes no sense to compare the returned handles directly. If you want to see if two handles point to the same object, use `env->IsSameObject(handle1, handle2)` or `equals` (although that checks more than just object identity).

The best explanation I can think of is that the "no-op" FindClass call stores a local reference at first slot of the local reference table (which is also where `Integer_class_0` points), which accidentally makes `Integer_class_0` reference the Integer class again. One way to validate this hypothesis would be:

```
env->FindClass("java/lang/String"); // replaces the local reference pointed to by Integer_class_0
jclass clsClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
jmethodID midClassToString = env->GetMethodID("toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring className = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(Integer_class_0, midClassToString);
```

The resulting `className` object should then contain `class java.lang.String` instead of `class java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: Can method and field IDs change between JNI function invocations? `NewGlobalRef` only takes `jobject` instances.

Comment: Good question! I believe (but cannot find the source of that belief for a second) that the method and field IDs remain valid as long as the Class remains loaded. Note that you may have several copies of the Class hanging around because of multiple ClassLoaders, so I would not try using the same method ID across differently-loaded copies of the Class.

Comment: Are `jobject` values always guaranteed to be zero if they refer to a null object reference? Or is there another method (akin to `IsSameObject`) that tests whether a `jobject` ref refers to a null object reference?

Comment: I think so but have no documentation to back that up, sorry.

Comment: [The spec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/design.html#accessing-fields-and-methods) says, “After the class is unloaded, the method or field ID becomes invalid.” which suggests that it stays valid up to this point (in case of bootstrap classes, the entire runtime). [`GetObjectRefType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getobjectreftype) suggests that there can be a difference between `NULL` and a valid reference to `null`. But since `IsSameObject` accepts `NULL`, `IsSameObject(ref, NULL)` should be sufficient to check for `null`.

Answer (score 6):

Mind [the JNI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/design.html#referencing-java-objects):

> The JNI divides object references used by the native code into two categories: *local* and *global* references. Local references **are valid for the duration of a native method call**, and are automatically freed after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until they are explicitly freed.
>
> Objects are passed to native methods as local references. **All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references**. The JNI allows the programmer to create global references from local references. JNI functions that expect Java objects accept both global and local references. A native method may return a local or global reference to the VM as its result.

You get a local reference from `(*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer")` within the `test0` method call and try to use it within the `test1` method call, despite it has been automatically freed when `test0` returned.

Accessing freed memory or invalid references can have arbitrary effects, including the possibility that an apparently unrelated operation changes the outcome.

To get a reference that persists between method calls, you have to use [`NewGlobalRef`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#newglobalref).

By the way, you can use [`IsSameObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#issameobject) to compare the references, without calling `equals` (which would have different semantics when overridden).

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of that. I had read the spec, but I hadn't connected all the dots.